# refresh the webpage on database update

Tags: php, websocket

I want to reflect the changes that occur immediately in the table in a database, on the webpage. I have been reading about websockets but I am not very clear about how to implement it. I was wondering that how could I be able to extract that new information is has been added to the table and how do I let the server push it towards the browser.

Comment: You may want to look into an AJAX solution, since Websockets aren't going to work in older browsers.

Comment: How big of a website are we talking about?

Comment: Agreed, AJAX might be better. The down side is you have to poll for changes. It might not be exactly what you want but it will be close enough.

Comment: The website isn't very big. It will have around 50-70 users trying to use the information at the same time and I need to show the updated tables as soon as the new entry is added to it.

Answer (score 1):

For pushing data to the users I tried with success http://pusherapp.com/.

As of how to reflect the change on the database to PusherApp, it depends on your architecture. If you have a beforeSave() callback, or you centralize SQL queries on one file, that's the place to handle it, if not you'll have to track all the places where you need to implement this behavior.

Comment: Well I have all my queries as php functions in a single file. As of now I had thought of using a function call when the new data is inserted by I am not how do I ask the function to display the table on that particular webpage with updated values.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a comet application i.e. longpollig - http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start