# how can I refresh a webpage using ajax, after database inserts

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a service running on a pc witch does some inserts in my (MySQL) database. What I want to do is everytime a new record is inserted in database to refresh automatically my webpage (I am using php). I read a relative post about updates

[refresh the webpage on database update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108860/refresh-the-webpage-on-database-update), but those updates were done "from" the webpage.

I also read another post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460297/automatically-refresh-the-webpage-just-after-a-new-database-entry,  didn't figure out how I can do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe `Comet` technology will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you do it**

Use JavaScript's `settimeout()` function to run an ajax request to your server at a set interval in which you send the id of the last record on the page. The use Javascripts window.location.reload() function to reset the page if the last record's id is different.

**Why you don't want to refresh the page**

This is bad user experience. You don't want the page refreshing out of no where. The best idea is to send the latest id on the current page to the server and check for any new ids. If there are new ideas send the records back via json and append them to the end of your results table.

Comment: I don't want to refresh the whole page but some graphs. What you say probably are completely correct, but I'm new in Javascript and I would apreciate some code samples, cause I can't understand them quite!

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is some complex but possible solution of your requirement!
In our scenario we have developed a sms-gateway and defining a trigger when ever any record is inserted we call a function that sends a sms to our gate way that behind that gateway we have developed our page. :)

In other way by defining timing ajax or many other ways where some what how our some resources are used, we have to compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to trigger an update of data on the page via AJAX as opposed to a full page refresh. You can potentially accomplish this using web sockets. A popular server-side implementation is [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Which uses the nodejs environment.

You could potentially write a [MySQL UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10) which executes in your trigger and signals nodejs to push more data (which may require writing a nodejs package as well). So, not trivial, but definitely doable :)

Comment: Thanks! This is closely to me, cause I feel more comfortable playing with sql than javascript. I 'll check this out.